How Safari do Reader mode?
Currently I'm reading some entries of IEP, they are not really readable to me. Luckily safari's reader mode (iPad) end my suffering, but sometimes I have to read in non-safari browsers. If you are using desktop version, could you check out how safari do this, and if possible, share me the code? So I can use stylus to model their way.
I try to do it on iPad, but it seems not possible.

I'm sorry not clear in decription, all I want are something like css sheet including font-size, line-height and spaceing for each elements.  Tuning thing are not trivial for me, and safari devs are master of typeseting by my view, so I just want to copy thier code if possible.
